# How to apply a force to a wheeled veichle and make wheel rotate ?

Tags: unity

I've a veichle with 4 wheel and 4 wheel collider.

My veichle is a toy.. so i would like to apply an impulse force (veichle rigidbody.addforce) to that veichle, move it and make wheel rotate...

How can i do ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to GameDev SE! Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are your possible options:

## 1. Full Physics

Apply the correct frictions to all physics materials and use a torque on wheels to make them rotate and push the whole body along with themselves.

## 2. Semi-Physics #1

Apply a force to the body as a whole, make the wheels lighter so they rotate by themselves as the body moves.

## 3. Semi-Physics #2

Drive the body with physics but exclude the wheels from physics and drive them using your own code - preferably just as an animation.

## 4. No Physics

Drive everything by yourself. This is probably the most stable option, but you probably don't need that much stability.